# R: UK choropleth with data from euro_example using my own dataset as colour gradients to show density of variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, choropleth

**My datasets:**

1 - Geometry points to plot the polygons that indicate the boundaries for the unst2 uk boundaries = [dataSetUK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veSEX.png).

2 - Simple table that has the same column for the different districts as dataset 1, but with a number respective to each one = [dataToUse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mRrO.png).
What I want to create is simply a chloropleth with the first dataset as the boundaries and the 2nd dataset used as a variable to indicate the density in each district of variable x.

**What I have tried:**

3 - https://medium.com/@traffordDataLab/lets-make-a-map-in-r-7bd1d9366098

4 - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tricolore/vignettes/choropleth_maps_with_tricolore.html

So from tutorial '3', I have tried it with the following code:

The dataset I end up with using this code: `dataFinal<- left_join(dataSetUK, dataToUse, by = "name")`
is: [dataFinal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZFIx.png)

What I would thought I would need to do is use the dataFinal$geometry, dataFinal$x_perc columns to plot the chloropleth, but I get an error when I run the ggplot function:

```
ggplot() +       
  geom_sf(data = sf_gm_census,     
          aes(fill = cut_number(percent, 5)),     
          alpha = 0.8,           
          colour = 'white',      
          size = 0.3) +               
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "PuBu",        
                    name = "No qualifications (%)") +       
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL,        
       title = "Residents with no qualifications in Greater Manchester, 2011",    
       subtitle = "Source: Table QS502EW, Census 2011",     
       caption = "Contains OS data © Crown copyright and database right (2018)") + 
  theme(panel.background = element_blank()) +   
  line = element_blank()
```

The error for this I get is: Error in ggplot() + geom_sf(data = sf_gm_census, aes(fill = cut_number(sf_gm_census$x_perc,  : 
  invalid (NULL) left side of assignment

When I remove all the following functions in the above code: labs, theme, line, scale_fill_brewer - then I get this error: Error: stat_sf requires the following missing aesthetics: geometry

Been working on this for 2 days now - help would be very much appreciated :D

I think I am missing something more fundamental here.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could link to the data somehow instead of posting screenshots of it (I do understand that this might not be possible here, in which case I apologize for requesting it).

Comment: apologies, thats a bit tough - if you think its really needed i could do that

Comment: I cannot do much since I do not have any data. But I can point two things. One is that you are using `sf_gm_census` in geom_sf(). Is this identical to `dataFinal`? The other thing is the column name, `percent` in geom_sf(). I do not see that name in your screen shot. I see `x_perc` instead. Can this be a cause?

Comment: I will try to upload the data onto github tomorrow - and yes you are correct - that was a mistake on my part - apologise for the confusion!

Comment: I managed to solve it - thank you anyways: seemed much easier now haha - I converted the dataSetUK to GeoJSON using - #save the dataset as a GeoJSON file:
`geojsonio::geojson_write(dataSetUK, file = "C:/Users/miera/Downloads/dataSetUK.geojson")` Then after reading the 2 datasets: `la_waste <- merge(la, waste, by.x = 'name', by.y = 'Category')`

`# Plot with ggplot2's sf geom`
`ggplot() +`
  `geom_sf(data = la_waste["x"], mapping = aes(fill = x), colour = "black", size = 0.3) +`
 `scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral") +`
  `theme_void()`

Comment: apologies for the convolution - im still learning the syntax of stack